# API LOGIN DO GOOGLE EM JAVA

Tags: java, api, google

Preciso fazer uma tela de registro em JAVA onde está tela, terá um botão de login com o google, pesquisei um pouco mas não achei muitos ensinamentos, apenas achei que precisaria de uma chave pelo google cloud e um arquivo xml mas não consegui encontrar, alguém pode ajudar?
Eu fui em alguns artigos de jdk e baixei para colocar na documentação no netbeans para os imports do google funcionar, mas não está funcionando e não sei onde colocar minha chave, podem em ajudar?

Comment: Para evitar descentralização de informações, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas continua funcional na [postagem que já havia feito antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/587784/70).